# Trace of a product

Tags: linear-algebra

From wiki and various resources, I have seen the following:

$$Tr(X^TY) = \sum_i \sum_j X_{ij} Y_{ij}$$

However, I cannot derive the RHS myself.

Can someone show me how to the RHS is derived ?

Comment: This is actually an inner product on the space of $n \times n$ real matrices that gives rise to the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix product of matrices $A$ and $B$ (assuming they have correct dimensions etc.) in components is

$(AB)_{ij}=\sum_k A_{ik}B_{kj}$.

Applying this to $A=X^T$, $B=Y$ yields

$(X^TY)_{ij}=\sum_k X_{ki}B_{kj}$

and taking the trace then yields

$\text{Tr}(X^TY)=\sum_i(X^TY)_{ii}=\sum_i\sum_k X_{ki}B_{ki}$

which is the RHS.